# Website images are not aligning inline on google chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, bootstrap-4

I seem to be having a problem aligning images inline on my site, I've done it plenty of times before but can't get my head round why its not working now  I have looked on Stackoverflow for similar questions but can't an answer.

Okay update.. after playing around with it using different styling methods I randomly opened the site in IE and firefox and saw that the site works perfectly fine. The question now is why isn't working on Google Chrome?

Link to website
  [ http://www.spartansafety.co.uk/shop-by-brand.html]

```css
.shop-by-brand li {
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="page-content">
                    <div class="shop-by-brand">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <img alt="Fristads logo" class="img-fluid"
                                    src="assets/img/Fristads_shop.png" style=
                                    "border: 1px solid #ccc;">
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <img alt="Pulsar logo" class="img-fluid"
                                    src="assets/img/Pulsar_shop.png" style=
                                    "border: 1px solid #ccc;">
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <img alt="Herock" class="img-fluid" src=
                                    "assets/img/Herock_shop.png" style=
                                    "border: 1px solid #ccc;">
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That CSS works, I've just manually tested it on your website. It seems the problem is that your styling isn't applied; I've inspected the website and your styling wasn't there.

Comment: In your style.css its says .shop-by-brand  {...} instead of .shop-by-brand li {...}. If I add the li it works for me. Maybe check this ?

Comment: @TA that's weird because it's 100% there

Answer (score 1):

I am modifying the CSS of the Code but uploading complete , use it and hopefully your problem would be solved.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="page-content">
                    <div class="shop-by-brand">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <img alt="Fristads logo" class="img-fluid"
                                    src="assets/img/Fristads_shop.png" style=
                                    "border: 1px solid #ccc;">
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <img alt="Pulsar logo" class="img-fluid"
                                    src="assets/img/Pulsar_shop.png" style=
                                    "border: 1px solid #ccc;">
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <img alt="Herock" class="img-fluid" src=
                                    "assets/img/Herock_shop.png" style=
                                    "border: 1px solid #ccc;">
                                </li>
<div class="clear"></div>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Your Modified CSS

```
   .shop-by-brand ul li {
float:left;
}
.clear{
clear:both;
}
```

Comment: What's the Problem happening @Will_Ghost16 Kindly let me know to solve your headache from this problem

Comment: same problem the was originally asked

Comment: Sure @Will_Ghost16 Kindly give me a minute to check. Thanks for patience

Comment: @Will_Ghost16 Friend Kindly check i have updated the code , also the website url is i think not properly working to live inspect it.   Kindly let me know when the website is corrected.

Answer (score 0):

another way you can solving using css below :

```css
.shop-by-brand li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put image width*height like below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="page-content">
                    <div class="shop-by-brand">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <img alt="Fristads logo" class="img-fluid"
                                    src="assets/img/Fristads_shop.png" height="42" width="42" style=
                                    "border: 1px solid #ccc;">
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <img alt="Pulsar logo" class="img-fluid"
                                    src="assets/img/Pulsar_shop.png" height="42" width="42" style=
                                    "border: 1px solid #ccc;">
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <img alt="Herock" class="img-fluid" src=
                                    "assets/img/Herock_shop.png" height="42" width="42" style=
                                    "border: 1px solid #ccc;">
                                </li>
<div class="clear"></div>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and your css should be

```
.shop-by-brand li {
  display:inline;
}
```